# conditional sapply to change levels of DF factors

Tags: r, regex, apply

I have a very messy dataset where researchers did not match levels of data across sessions.  In one session, a '[digit]: ' or '[digit] : ' was added.

I created a dataframe of session 3, 6, and 10 visits from the SWAN dataset. You can download what I'm working with here: [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b2SS1PFvp1VZn89WJVpWcGNzRchBsNAa)

Here's an example of the levels:

```
levels(dat$ABLECLM)
 [1] "(1) Always"                              "(2) Almost Always"                      
 [3] "(3) Sometimes"                           "(4) Almost Never"                       
 [5] "(5) Never"                               "(6) No Intercourse In Last 6 Mons"      
 [7] "(1) 1 : Always"                          "(2) 2 : Almost always"                  
 [9] "(3) 3 : Sometimes"                       "(4) 4 : Almost never"                   
[11] "(5) 5 : Never"                           "(6) 6 : No intercourse in last 6 months"
[13] "(2) Almost always"                       "(4) Almost never"                       
[15] "(6) No intercourse in last 6 months"
```

I wrote this function to use in an apply function:

```
match_levels <- function(column){
    if(is.factor(column)){
        levels(column) <- sapply(column, tolower)
        levels(column) <- sapply(column,function(x) sub('\\d: |\\d : ', '', levels(x)))
        return(column)
    }else{
        return(column)
    }
}
```

It works on a single column, but when I try and apply to each column I have:

```
dat <- read.csv(<data_link>)
df <- data.frame(apply(dat,2, function(x) x=match_levels(x)))
```

I get this:

```
levels(as.factor(df$ABLECLM))
 [1] "(1) 1 : Always"  
 [2] "(1) Always"  
 [3] "(2) 2 : Almost always" 
 [4] "(2) Almost always"    
 [5] "(2) Almost Always"     
 [6] "(3) 3 : Sometimes"     
 [7] "(3) Sometimes"         
 [8] "(4) 4 : Almost never" 
 [9] "(4) Almost never"      
 [10] "(4) Almost Never"      
 [11] "(5) 5 : Never"         
 [12] "(5) Never"
```

Comment: What output you want ?

Comment: Have you checked if `sapply(dat, is.factor)`?  Probably your `if` clause is activated.

Comment: Hi @jay.sf I did check that but good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your original logic of updating the levels of the factor, rather than the value of the variable, which requires factoring again.

```
new_levels <- function(vec) {
  if (is.factor(vec)) {
    lvls <- gsub('\\d: |\\d : ', '', tolower(levels(vec)))
    dups <- which(duplicated(substr(lvls,1,3)))
    lvls[dups] <- lvls[dups-1]
    lvls[dups] <- lvls[dups-1]
    levels(vec) <- lvls
    return(vec)
  } else {
    return(vec)
  }
}

df[] <- lapply(df, new_levels)
```

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(lapply(df, new_levels),lapply(dat, match_levels))
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr        min        lq       mean     median         uq       max
    lapply(df, new_levels)   4.875398   5.13453   6.654272   5.737605   6.568733  80.17889
 lapply(dat, match_levels) 516.539473 532.93423 539.665595 536.944488 541.752497 615.87178
```

Comment: do you know why it doesn't work to *apply* over the column? I understand that your version is better for efficiency (thank you!) and actually using lapply works on the original function but I don't understand why it didn't work with the apply(dat, 2, match_levels).

Comment: My understanding is that `apply` applies a function to the margins of an array or matrix, which means it strips the factors while processing since factors are not part of matrices. Since the function operates on the factor levels not on the value of the variable, the result is as if nothing has happened. The resulting data.frame is the same as the original sans the factor info, all variables are now type character instead of factor.

Comment: I edited my answer to take care of duplicates with small differences, such as "mon" and "month', "peri" and "perimenopause". I'm replacing all duplicates with first instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using exactly the right tools. However, it's no fun, to `gsub` every single factor in detail. Instead we can exploit the neat numbers in front of the factors. First, we `split` the levels along those numbers using the result of `gsub`. Next, we choose each second level `w=2` which looks cleanest to me. Finally we do the same with the entire vector what we did with the levels, `gsub` them and create a `factor` out of it using the `labs` we chose before as `labels=`.

```
dat <- read.csv('~/Downloads/proj3_data_before_cleaning.csv', stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

f <- function(x, w=2) {
  if (is.factor(x)) {
    lv <- levels(x)
    lvs <- split(lv, gsub('^(\\(\\d+\\)).*', '\\1', lv))
    labs <- sapply(lvs, `[`, w)
    factor(gsub('^(\\(\\d+\\)).*', '\\1', as.character(x), perl=TRUE), labels=labs)
  } else {
    x
  }
}   

dat[] <- lapply(dat[], f)  ## apply

summary(dat)  ## check
```